# Free up memory in MobileSafari (iPhone/iPad) from cached images

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, webkit, mobile-safari

The iPad stops loading large images after about 8 or 9 images for me, since the page runs into its allocated memory limits.

Since I'm showing these images one at a time, I'd like to remove the old ones from the browser cache so I don't hit the limit.

Any ideas on how to do this in javascript?

Answer (score 5):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986039/ipad-iphone-browser-crashing-when-loading-images-in-javascript) for a good answer.  In a nutshell, you should use the same image objects and set the src instead of creating new images.