# Determine where my memory leak comes from using Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks

My Google Chrome taskbar clearly tells me that I have a memory leak. I've checked that I'm flushing everything, but still haven't solved the problem.

Is there a way to determine *what* causes the leak using Google Chrome Developer Tools (or some other tool)?

Comment: Did you run a profile or an audit from the Developer Tools window?

Comment: Well I'm taking heap snapshots at various times, and comparing them. No significant leak seems to come from the heap.

Comment: 99% its the DOM. How bad is the leak ? Give us some numbers.

Comment: @c69: The leak is around 100MB per 15 minutes. And I'm pretty sure the DOM is being cleaned properly.

Comment: @Randomblue Bloody hell. What is your app doing ?

Comment: @c69: It's loading images from Flickr at a rate of 1 picture per second. I've made sure that any javascript reference is continuously cleaned and that the DOM is always cleaned also. I starting to think that it has to do with the way Google Chrome is dealing with the images.

Comment: lol, WebKit + lost of images (like more than 100) = trouble. Pure thing crashes even from slightest things like 1MB data:uri backgrounds. You should try checking this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986039/ipad-iphone-browser-crashing-when-loading-images-in-javascript

Comment: @c69: Thanks. That's probably the problem. I will double check that everything works fine on Firefox or IE.

Comment: `t.name="justin";`
`var temp=t.name;`
`t.name={};`
this does not flush the object, be sure you're cleaning all references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is good article about memory leaks - http://gent.ilcore.com/2011/08/finding-memory-leaks.html