# Does detach in JQuery destroys the node in DOM?

Tags: jquery, dom

Does the detach method in JQuery actually destroys the node in DOM? For example, if I do:

```
$("#myDiv").detach().appendTo($("#container"));
```

Will destroy the original `#myDiv` node, and create a new node to append in `#container`? Or it will be the same node?

With destroy, I mean that the memory location that stores the node within the browser is freed when I execute `detach`. Or JQuery does save a reference (not a copy) of the node, preventing it to be freed, and be available to re-attach later?

Comment: What do you mean by "destroy"? What do you consider "the same node"? Clarify your terms and maybe we can help you, or else just [read the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) and [try it yourself](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: detach keeps data bound to element, is it your question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942070/differences-between-detach-hide-and-remove-jquery

Comment: As I understand, `detach` keeps just the JQuery data, but what about the actual piece of memory corresponding to the node whitin the DOM?

Comment: All datas are kept, not only jquery ones

Comment: The vote as duplicate is wrong : that's not the same question.

Comment: check jquery source, detach use getAll function to store DOM node(s) inside a DOM node list, so the reappended node is still the same

Comment: @dystroy ya and indeed this is a interresting question, deserving more upvotes imho

Comment: Thanks @A.Wolff. Do you know in which file of the source code is the function you mention? This is the source code in GitHub, right? https://github.com/jquery/jquery

Comment: here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L123

Comment: Agreed, this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Please vote for reopen this question :) As @A.Wolff says, it seems that `detach` stores the original node. But I'll try to make some tests with Chrome DevTools (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling) to see how the node's memory is handled (as soon as I can figure how to do it, though XD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$("#myDiv")` object keeps as property `0` the relevant element, even after you detached it. When you append, you really append the same element, it's not a new one.

You can check that by noticing that child elements are also restored again. Note that the `remove` function has the same behavior expect it cleans jQuery data linked to the element and its childs. You can also see your element(s) by issuing `console.dir($("#myDiv").detach())`.