# iOS7 cordova application crash due do memory pressure after Url loadRequest

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, uiwebview, ios7

We are using cordova-2.3.0 application and running in iOS7 iPad, when loading may html page URL its working, but then a few URL getting crashed(less then iOS7 working fine). While debug, had get 'Terminated App due to memory Pressure'.

Would appreciate if anyone could help me out of it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986039/ipad-iphone-browser-crashing-when-loading-images-in-javascript?lq=1  this may give you an answer