# Browser closes automatically in ipad

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm using kendo splitter in my application. I'm loading large amount of data while clicking on grid.In normal windows desktop or mac desktop it works fine.

But in ipad mini browser closes automatically while loading data. Even i can't see the console for which error it was. I need to add any separate js Files for that. Any one facing this type of issues.

Image attached for this...(this image is normal desktop mode)[image]

Comment: I don't think it closes due to js error, use Console app from /Applications/Utilities to read the device log when it happens, use Xcode Organiser to get Safari crash reports.

Comment: Actually i have kendo splitter in so many pages... But in this page data load is too high compared to other pages... other pages are working fine... i tried to connect this in safari in mac but it also closes automatically...

Comment: I have no idea what kendo splitter is. What I meant is that you have both console log and crash report to work with.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986039/ipad-iphone-browser-crashing-when-loading-images-in-javascript?rq=1